# GeoServer - Unaccent function

Tags: geoserver

PostgreSQL databases have an extension called unaccent to remove accents from words. Is there some function on GeoServer to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Not currently](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions), but it would be easy for you (or someone) to add, the [actual code would be pretty simple](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/StaticGeometry.java#L451):

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322152/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-accents-and-convert-a-whole-string-to-regular-lette) gives the necessary clues, so:

```
public static String strRemoveAccents(String s1) {
    if (s1 == null) return null;
    return StringUtils.stripAccents(s1);
}
```

The hard bit is finding some test cases etc.

**Update** see [this issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6208) for progress.